Fourier Transform and Audio Processing
Most audio capturing software automatically distills the audio into distinct frequencies with Fourier transform. This makes audio editing much easier. I have a project where I want to show the application of Fourier transform in audio processing. I need a software or some package that can analyze an audio file (.mp3) and transcribe the audio into a wave function equation. That way I can manually do the Fourier transform derivation and show the frequencies. Thank you.

MATLAB can open .mp3 files and save as .wav .

"transcribe it into a wave function equation" The writing down of equations is the boring part that you'll have to do yourself. All software (the FFT) will give you is the coefficients that need to go into the equation. And what's the illustrative advantage of writing down "these 20ms of signal are $14 \cdot e^{j0} + (-23j+1) \cdot  e^{j 2.5 t}  + (23j+1) \cdot  e^{-j2.5 t} + …$ with 960 summands, for example? If they understand the Fourier Transform before, they will still understand it and see a gigantic equation that should better be visualized graphically, if they don't understand the

Fourier transform before, then they won't understand it after, and you'd have scared them with a gigantic equation. If you want to have a signal for which you can write down the Fourier transform as analytical equation, generate a tone. Don't need to use software to transform that, that's the point.
